# Using SKTransition for inherited SKScene classes

Tags: swift, swift3, sprite-kit, uikit, swift-playground

I'm making a playground which is like a 'presentation', aka you can add slides and click buttons to move forward and backward. However, I'm trying to use SKTransition to go from scene1 to scene2, but the transition rolls over my title and buttons. Could really use some help, thanks!

Main Code -

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 640, height: 480)

let view = SKView(frame: frame)
view.showsDrawCount = true
view.showsNodeCount = true
view.showsFPS = true

let scene = MainScene(size: CGSize(width: 640, height: 480))
view.presentScene(scene)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

MainScene.swift -

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import PlaygroundSupport

public class Slide: SKScene {

    public var title: SKLabelNode!
    public var info: UITextView!

    public func setter() {

        self.title = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
        self.title.verticalAlignmentMode = .center
        self.title.color = SKColor.white
        self.title.position = CGPoint(x: 320, y: 440)

        let framer = CGRect(x: 40, y: 60, width: 560, height: 360)

        self.info = UITextView(frame: framer)
        self.info.font = UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: 20)
        self.info.textAlignment = .center
        self.info.textColor = UIColor.white
        self.info.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

        self.backgroundColor = SKColor.black
    }


}

public class MainScene: SKScene {

    public var button1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Next")
    public var button2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Previous")
    public var sceneNo = 1

    public var title: SKLabelNode!
    public var info: UITextView!

    public var scene1 = Slide()
    public var scene2 = Slide()

    public override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        backgroundColor = SKColor.black

        scene1.setter()
        scene2.setter()
        setTheStage()

    }

    public func setTheStage() {

        switch sceneNo {
        case 1:
            setScene1()
        default:
            setScene2()
        }

    }

    public func setScene1() {

        scene1.title?.text = "Scene1Title"
        scene1.title?.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)

        title = scene1.title

        addChild(title)
        addButtons()

    }

    public func setScene2() {

        scene2.title?.text = "Scene2Title"
        scene2.info?.text = "Scene2Text"

        title = scene2.title
        info = scene2.info

        let transition = SKTransition.flipVertical(withDuration: 1.0)
        self.view?.presentScene(scene2, transition: transition)

        addChild(title)
        self.view?.addSubview(info)
        addButtons()

    }

    public func addButtons() {
        self.button1.position = CGPoint(x: 600, y: 40)
        self.button2.position = CGPoint(x: 40, y: 40)

        if sceneNo < 5 {
            addChild(self.button1)
        }

        if sceneNo > 1 {
            addChild(self.button2)
        }
    }

    override public func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch in touches {

            let location = touch.location(in: self)

            if(button1.contains(location)) {

                self.button1.removeFromParent()
                self.button2.removeFromParent()
                self.title.removeFromParent()

                if sceneNo > 1 {

                    self.info.removeFromSuperview()

                }

                sceneNo += 1
                setTheStage()
            }
            else if(button2.contains(location)) {

                self.button1.removeFromParent()
                self.button2.removeFromParent()
                self.title.removeFromParent()
                self.info.removeFromSuperview()

                sceneNo -= 1
                setTheStage()

            }
        }
    }

}
```